# Exporting multiline feeds to a single line

Tags: database, oracle8i

I need to dump 10 tables data to 10 different csv files in oracle 8i,regularly
Few columns like address have multiline data. I require to convert the multi line to a single line before dumping the data to csv.

one of Ex : address column in customer table

```
340 University Ave 
Palo Alto 
CA 94301
United States
```

required format : col1...340 University Ave Palo Alto CA 94301  United States...coln

Is there anyway to write generic code to dump the data,which handles multiline feed as well ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Export to CSV avoiding newlines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739929/oracle-sql-export-to-csv-avoiding-newlines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just grab the whole block of text, remove any instances of `\n` (newline) (and replace them with spaces if that aids the formatting) and that will give you the format you want.